# Can I Record 4ch in a zoom H4n with my setup?

Tags: recording, portable-recorder, zoom-h4n, live-performance

I need to record a live session, and I am trying not to buy anything else.
I have a Zoom h4n as a recorder / mixer
mics:
1 Shure SM 57 dinamic mic(to record percussion) (xlr cable)
1 Shure SM 11 lavalier non-phantom mic (to record classic guitar) (xlr output)
1 pair of headset mics in a wireless set for voices recording (can get a mono mixed line level signal to 1/4´´ plug) 
1 Jamman Solo looper playing prerecorded loops (line level 1/4´´ plug out)

So, can I plug both the mics (xlr cables to a splitter cable -2 xlr to a single stereo miniplug) to plug to the reverse miniplug input (designed for "external stereo microphone") hopefully getting a stereo track with hard pan Left and Right getting each mic with no alteration of the other in the pair?
can I plug the wireless system on imput 1 and the Jamman looper on imput 2, getting those tracks also with hard pan?
If anyone tried similar settings, please report the results, so I can faithfully create the splitter (2xlr-to-1setero-miniplug) I think I am needing.
Thanks!!!
Cheers
Augusto

Comment: what does the manual say?

Comment: the only metion of the backwards input is for "external microphone"... the other aspects, I am confithent that can configure adecuately

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with this is going to be the gain setting for the external mic. The H4N is expecting stereo input, but you are using dual mono with two different mics which are likely to have different input level profiles.